# Encoding issue when parsing XML in R

Tags: r, xml, parsing, encoding

I am having problems with parsing xml's that contain non-latin character data. For example I am trying to parse following xml:

```
<PersonFullName>
  <PersonCode>
    9999999999999
  </PersonCode>
  <FirstName>
    ANDŽĀRS
  </FirstName>
  <LastName>
    DŽANDĒRĒKĀ
  </LastName>
</PersonFullName>
```

When I use following code

```
library(XML)
input <- xmlTreeParse(file = "test.xml", encoding = "UTF-8")
print(input)
```

I get following result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PersonFullNameVSAA>
  <PersonCode>9999999999999
                </PersonCode>
  <FirstName>ANDÅ½Ä€RS
                </FirstName>
  <LastName>DÅ½ANDÄ’RÄ’KÄ€
                </LastName>
</PersonFullNameVSAA>
```

The xml is correctly encoded in UTF-8. I don't know what else can I do to get characters in correct format.

Comment: What happens when you don't specify the encoding when calling the `xmlTreeParse()` function? Like: just `xmlTreeParse(file = "test.xml")`?

Comment: Same thing happens

Comment: Run `Sys.getlocale('LC_CTYPE')` to see what your local encoding is. If it is not `UTF-8`, make sure to set it to `UTF-8`. If you already have `UTF-8` set, then you may have to import the xml file as text and use `stringi::stri_conv()` to convert the text from whatever encoding it is to `UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks @Abdou but none of the suggestions helped :/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the approaches in the comments worked.

My encoding on the Windows machine is Windows-1252, as can be determined by

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
```

It seems that the XML package correctly parses the UTF-8, but returns strings with the local encoding, which may then be interpreted in the wrong way by R.

I collect my output in a data frame containing character vectors. The solution for me was to translate the resulting data frame with `iconv`:

```
apply(mydf, 2, function(x) iconv(x, from = "UTF-8", to = "Windows-1252"))
```